# String array adds duplicate item

Tags: java, arrays

I try to add items to meters array. Each item comes back from `Meter.load(sc)`, which returns a Meter. When I try to print the items in order to check the output,
the first test prints out correctly all the items, but the second test fails, showing just the last item duplicated. Because of this problem, I can not call `getMeterNumbers` from other class.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

```
public class CommercialAccount extends Account {

private Meter[] meters;

public CommercialAccount(AccountNumber accountNumber, Meter[] meters) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.meters = meters;
}

public CommercialAccount(Scanner sc, AccountNumber accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    meters = new Meter[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        meters[i] = Meter.load(sc);
        System.out.println("Test 1: " + meters[i].toString());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Test 2: " + meters[i].toString());
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return accountNumber.toString() + " C " + meters.length;
}

public MeterNumber[] getMeterNumbers() {
    MeterNumber[] ms = new MeterNumber[meters.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
        ms[i] = meters[i].getMeterNumber();
    }
    return ms;
}
}
```

The console prints

```
Test 1: 356 926 850 
Test 1: 101 949 516 
Test 1: 911 221 326 
Test 1: 241 329 198 
Test 1: 569 096 301 
Test 1: 629 316 190 
Test 1: 537 224 159 
Test 2: 537 224 159 
Test 2: 537 224 159 
Test 2: 537 224 159 
Test 2: 537 224 159 
Test 2: 537 224 159 
Test 2: 537 224 159 
Test 2: 537 224 159
```

UPDATE:
 Found my mistake, it is all properties in my Meter class are static so this is the reason why. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible causes to your problem :

1. `Meter.load(sc)` always returns the same `Meter` instance. That would explain why all the elements in the array are identical.
2. All the properties in the `Meter` class are static, so all instances share the same values.

EDIT: based on the comment by the OP, the problem was defining the properties in the Meter class as static.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't the `"Test 1"` statements all print the same as well?

Comment: +1 brilliant. My mistake is your second option. All properties in my Meter class are static so this is the reason why. Thank you.

Comment: @Mena No, the "Test 1" prints happen after each call to `Meter.load(sc)` changes the properties of the instance, so you are seeing the state of a single instance at different points in time (or the state of static properties of a class at different points in time).

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a simple exemple. If you do this :

```
int n = 5;
Foo[] foo = new Foo[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    foo[i] = getFoo("test" + i);
    System.out.println("Test 1: " + foo[i].toString());
}

for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Test 2: " + foo[i].toString());
}

private Foo getFoo(String s)
{
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.s = s;
    return f;
}

private class Foo
{
    public String s;

    public String toString()
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

It's working, as each element of `foo` are distinct instances.

```
Test 1: test0
Test 1: test1
Test 1: test2
Test 1: test3
Test 1: test4
Test 2: test0
Test 2: test1
Test 2: test2
Test 2: test3
Test 2: test4
```

But in this case (it must be yours) :

```
int n = 5;
Foo[] foo = new Foo[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    foo[i] = getFoo("test" + i);
    System.out.println("Test 1: " + foo[i].toString());
}

for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Test 2: " + foo[i].toString());
}

private static Foo getFoo(String s)
{
    Foo f = Foo.f;
    f.s = s;
    return f;
}

private static class Foo
{
    public static Foo f = new Foo();

    public String s;

    public String toString()
    {
        return s;
    }
}

Test 1: test0
Test 1: test1
Test 1: test2
Test 1: test3
Test 1: test4
Test 2: test4
Test 2: test4
Test 2: test4
Test 2: test4
Test 2: test4
```

It's not working, the first loop is good as the array is empty, each element is just set has the last value. The second loop fails as the array is full, each element refers to the same object.

=> Modify your `load` method in order to return distinct instances.

Comment: This is a nice explanation, but as the OP wrote, this wasn't the problem. Problem was static members in the Meter class.